# Save or rename file based on file contents

Tags: file, perl, rename

I'm trying to use Perl to rename files based on their contents.  I have some code that will return the first part of the filename, but need two other components in the file name.  I need the job number and the date which I will show the example.  Not sure of the code to save the file.  Below is the first section of code I use to make a list from a text file:

```
open(INFILE,"JAR28235.txt") or die "could not open file for reading!\n";
open(OUTFILE, '>????.txt') or die "Cannot open ????.txt: $!";

my @output;

while(<INFILE>) {
    chomp;
    next if /^\s*$/;

    my @fields = split;

    foreach my $field (@fields) {
            push @output, $field
            if $field =~ /^\*?[A-Z][A-Z0-9]{4}235/;
                
    }
}

    my @fields1 = split;
    foreach my $field1 (@fields1) {
            push @output1, $field1
            if $field1 =~ /JOB[0-9]{5}/;
   
    }
}

        $file = $field,"#"$field1"-"22356"."txt";
```

What I'm missing from this for the file name is the job number which can be added with a [0-9]{5}\ and the date which will be a fixed julian 5 digit date.  The filename will look like A01YC235#25011-22356.txt.  A01YC235 and #25011 will be from the file which are both in the file.  The -22356 will be put in the code for that specific date.  I need the output file saved this way.  The input file is JAR28235#0222.txt.  The last four numbers increment by 1.  Below is a sample of what I need to pull out of the file to rename the file.  The date that's bolded is when the job ran last.  If I can get the jobname, below is L27YG235 and job number, 03635 to be the first part of the file name, I can just put in the julian date for 22 DEC 2022.
So, from below, I want to grab L27YG235#03635-22356.txt  The 22356 is the julian date for December 22, 2022.  I added the second part of the code where I'm trying to grab the job number from JOB03635.

00.55.45 JOB03635 ---- THURSDAY,  22 DEC 2022 ----
00.55.45 JOB03635  ICH70001I $$MP235  LAST ACCESS AT 00:55:45 ON THURSDAY, DECEMBER 22, 2022
00.55.45 JOB03635  $HASP373                       J E S 2  J O B  L O G  --  S Y S T E M  V 4 Y M  --  N O D E  W A D I S

00.55.45 JOB03635 ---- THURSDAY,  22 DEC 2022 ----
00.55.45 JOB03635  ICH70001I $$MP235  LAST ACCESS AT 00:55:45 ON THURSDAY, **DECEMBER 22, 2022**
00.55.45 **JOB03635**  $HASP373 **L27YG235** STARTED - INIT 40   - CLASS R        - SYS V4YM
00.55.45 JOB03635  IEF403I L27YG235 - STARTED - TIME=00.55.45
00.55.45 JOB03635  OPS4200I MESSAGE: '0'
00.55.45 JOB03635  -                                      -----TIMINGS (MINS.)------                          -----PAGING COUNTS----STARTED - INIT 40   - CLASS R        - SYS V4YM
00.55.45 JOB03635  IEF403I L27YG235 - STARTED - TIME=00.55.45
00.55.45 JOB03635  OPS4200I MESSAGE: '0'
00.55.45 JOB03635  -                                      -----TIMINGS (MINS.)------                          -----PAGING COUNTS----

Comment: The code assembles "fields" with phrases like `A01YC235` (and a possible leading `*`) in `@output` ... how do you know which from the array to use for the filename?  (Say, `@output` ends up with 5 elements after the loop over all lines, and now you want to rename the file -- which of those five do you use to construct the new name?)  I guess I don't really understand what exactly need be done...

Comment: I think we need a sample input file.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick and dirty script,
I basically took your while loop and moved it into a function, you pass it the file name.
The function get_data opens the file and is your while loop.
Here you parse the file, line by line, and split out strings on whitespace.
And we do some if/else statements to find a matching string, you will probably need to fine tune this.
Then pass the data back.
If you want to do something with the date you can.
Next construct a file name how you like and use File::Copy rename the file.
This works for me with your test data.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use diagnostics;
use File::Copy qw(move);

# put your file name here:
my $filename = "/tmp/r/sample.txt";

my ($first_part,$job_number,$weekday,$month,$day,$year) = get_data($filename);

print qq|first_part: '$first_part',job_number;'$job_number',weekday:'$weekday',month:'$month',day:'$day',year:'$year'\n|;

# if you want to do somthing with the date do it here

my $newname = $first_part."#".$job_number.$month.$day.$year.".txt";

print qq|newname:'$newname'\n|;

# use File::Copy to rename the files
rename($filename,$newname)|| die ("Error Renaming File");


sub get_data {
my $filename = shift;
open(INFILE,$filename) or die "could not open file for reading!\n";

my ($first_part,$job_number,$weekday,$month,$day,$year);

    while(<INFILE>) {
        chomp;
        next if /^\s*$/;

        my @fields = split;
        my $is_date = 0;
        foreach my $field (@fields) {
                
                if (($field =~ /^\*?[A-Z][A-Z0-9]{4}235/) and (!$first_part) ){ #L27YG235
                    $first_part = $field;
                    print qq|matched $field\n|;
                }
                #else {print qq|No match '$field'\n|;}
                
                if ($field =~ /JOB([0-9]{5})/){
                    $job_number= $1;
                }
                elsif ($field =~ /SUNDAY|MONDAY|TUESDAY|WEDNESDAY|THURSDAY|FRIDAY|SATURDAY/){
                    $weekday =  $field;
                    $is_date= 1;
                }
                elsif ($field eq '----') { 
                    $is_date= 0;
                }
                elsif ($is_date){
                    $is_date++; 
                }
                
                if ($is_date == 2){
                $day = $field;
                }
                elsif ($is_date == 3){
                    $month = $field
                }
                elsif ($is_date == 4){
                    $year = $field
                }
                elsif ($is_date == 5){
                    $is_date = 0;
                }
                
            }
        }
    return ($first_part,$job_number,$weekday,$month,$day,$year);
}


print "\ndone\n";
    
1;
```

Comment: Thanks.  I'll keep this for future projects.